# Laravel. Run a single type job on one of the multiple instances at a time

Tags: php, laravel, queue

My Laravel queue setup has multiple instances that are horizontally scalable and run with the following command (corn):

`php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default,low`

Now, I need to add one more type `superlow` that has to be single-threaded. The queue workers should pick up this type of job only one at a time and prevent other workers from running it until it is finished.

`php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default,low,superlow`

1. The queue type is `database`
2. I couldn't find this kind of setup option in the official documentation

Comment: *The queue workers should pick up this type of job only one at a time and prevent other workers from running it until it is finished.* this describes how queued jobs work always unless you mean only a single superlow job (regardless what it is) can be running at a time

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is not clear. Let's say we have 10 superlow jobs and 5 workers. One of the workers picks it up. The other workers won't pick up any supelow job until the current one is done. By they can pick up high, low, default with any time.

Comment: There's no directly way to do this but you might be able to "hack" it by running a scheduled task every minute [on a single server](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-tasks-on-one-server) and [without overlap](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps). That task can be something like `Artisan::call('queue:work --once --queue=superlow')` or something like this.